# Conditional .htaccess 301 redirect when file name contains "extra" and ".php" and "id=XYZ"

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, drupal

I am a non-technical person so kindly bear with me.

I am trying to 301 redirect old files that return 404 errors such as the ones given below to my home page http://www.innovateonline.info/ :

```
extra.php?id=1149
?view=article&id=126
?view=article&id=668&action=synopsis
?view=person&id=1
```

I am using .htaccess and the site CMS is Drupal. I cannot redirect all files ending in .php as some Drupal admin files might end in that extension. Is there a way to conditionally redirect all files that contain "extra.php?id=*" and "?view=article&id=*"?

I have the below rules created so far but the first two are not really scalable (the third one redirecting all .pdf extensions is the only bulk handler I have succeeded in creating so far):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=article&id=126&action=article$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http:// www. innovateonline. info? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=article&id=258&action=article$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http:// www. innovateonline. info? [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .pdf$
RewriteRule ^(.*).pdf$ http://www.innovateonline.info? [R=301,L]
```

Can someone please help me create a .htaccess code for the above conditions? Appreciate your help with this and thank you in advance!

Thanks,
Ameet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=article&id=(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1000)(&|$) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=article&id=(668)&action=synopsis [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=person&id=1
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ http://www.innovateonline.info? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1149(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^extra\.php$ http://www.innovateonline.info? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Great, thanks Jon! Quick question - is there a way to add a catch all for the id=? For example if there were articles 1-1000 that needed to redirected, is it possible to do this by adding id=(1-1000) or similar?

Comment: I added the above code but the redirect does not seem to be working for http://www.innovateonline.info/?view=article&id=258 or http://www.innovateonline.info/?view=article&id=668&action=synopsis or http://www.innovateonline.info/extra.php?id=1149 but it does work for http://www.innovateonline.info/?view=person&id=1

Comment: For 1-1000, just use `(?:[0-9]{1,3}|1000)`. See the edit above

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The extra.php issue still remains though... and those id's are from 1-5000 so will the code look something like: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^extra\.php$?id=(?:[0-9]{1,3}|5000)(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^extra\.php$ http://www.innovateonline.info? [R=301,L]

Comment: @Ameet that's not how the regex works. `[0-9]{1,3}` means 1, 2, or 3 digits, so max of 999. And the `|1000` means, "or 1000", making the entire thing: 1-1000. For 1-5000 you need: `(?:[1-4]?[0-9]{1,3}|5000)`, so an optional 1-4 for the first digit, then 999, or 5000.

Comment: that worked like a dream! Thanks a ton for all your help! I owe you. Next time you're in the Bay area, please ping me - drinks and food are on me. Cheers, Ameet :)